# Utilizando gerador de CPF no Postman

Tags: api, testes, postman

Estou realizando diversos testes de cadastro via Postman e gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de gerar automaticamente um CPF no body do POST que estou enviando.

Quem sabe via Faker?

Comment: Ele até tem o Faker integrado, mas acho que não com a opção de gerar CPF.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para qualquer tipo de dados você pode [**setar as variáveis**](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#using-variables-in-scripts) no *Pre-request Script*, independente se é um valor aleatório para CPF ou para outra coisa.

Use `pm.globals` para definir uma variável global, exemplo:

```js
pm.globals.set("foo", "bar");
```

Use `pm.collectionVariables` para definir uma variável para coleção, exemplo:

```js
pm.collectionVariables.set("foo", "bar");
```

Use `pm.environment`para definir uma variável para o **Environment** (no ambiente selecionado atualmente, confira no menu a opção *Environment*):

```js
pm.environment.set("foo", "bar");
```

> Se você tiver acesso de visualização, mas não de edição a um Environment, seu código de script afetará apenas o valor atual e não será sincronizado ou compartilhado com sua equipe.

### Definindo variáveis locais

Para o seu caso definir uma variável local, ou seja no *Pre-request Script*, que será um valor temporário deve servir muito bem (a não ser que vá criar um processo com um passo a passo disparado dinamicamente, mas depende do caso e ou necessidade), exemplo:

```js
pm.variables.set("foo", "bar");
```

Não é necessário *Faker.js*, isso é só um facilitador, você mesmo pode escrever qualquer script de qualquer forma a hora que achar necessário, tem um exemplo nessa pergunta de como gerar um CPF: [Gerador de CPF em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/244457/3635)

Por fim faça o seguinte, no seu *Pre-request Script* adicione:

```js
pm.variables.set("cpf", gerarCPF());

function gerarCPF() {
      return ...;
}
```

é só um *pseudocódigo* para ter ideia de como implementar, e então se sua requisição for GET, faça algo como `http://foo/bar?cpf={{cpf}}`, veja o resultado na imagem do `http://postman-echo.com/get`:

> [image: GET no postman]

Se for POST basta passar a variável `{{cpf}}` no body, veja o resultado na imagem do `http://postman-echo.com/post`:

> [image: POST no postman]

---

### Integrando ferramentas de terceiros com `pm.sendRequest`

Não é necessário usar especificamente *Faker.js* e ele **não é exatamente integrado**, na verdade *"integrar"* é algo que fazemos usando `pm.sendRequest`, então se conhece outra biblioteca que tenha gerador de CPF, CNPJ ou qualquer outra necessidade, você pode usar o `pm.sendRequest` somado a um `eval` (isso roda em Sandbox) para injetar o script:

```js
pm.sendRequest("https://cdn.foobar/lib.js", (error, response) => {
    if (error || response.code !== 200) {
        pm.expect.fail('Could not load external library');
    }

    eval(response.text());

    pm.variables.set("cpf", gerador.CPF());
});
```

Algumas bibliotecas usam o objeto `window` para que tenha acesso a lib, como o *Pre-Request Script* roda em um sandbox é necessário criar um objeto `window` próprio:

```js
window = {};

pm.sendRequest("https://cdn.barbaz/lib.js", (error, response) => {
    if (error || response.code !== 200) {
        pm.expect.fail('Could not load external library');
    }

    eval(response.text());

    pm.variables.set("cpf", window.gerador.CPF());
});
```

Note que você também pode usar o `require(...)` (se a biblioteca usada suportar), o que pode facilitar muito.

---

Aproveitando, você pode usar o `pm.sendRequest()` para criar o passo a passo de testes específicos aonde precise de uma sequencia de requisições ordenadas para obter um resultado, mas isso é um assunto muito além.

Documentação: https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#sending-requests-from-scripts

Comment: +1 pela boa resposta e explicar o uso dos parametros, estive procurando isso esses dias e não achei nada completo numa unica resposta :)